# My Calender extender is not working with ajax control toolkit

Tags: ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have installed ajax control toolkit.dll . but my ajax controls are not working . Tried for calender filter extender nothing is working .

getting following error in DOM:

Uncaught Error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll. ScriptResource.axd:22

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ScriptResource.axd:813

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ScriptResource.axd:1653

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_Wrapper' of undefined

Please help 
thank you.

Comment: tried with ToolkitScriptManager still same issue.

Comment: Finally got the answer ....

Comment: what was the solution

Comment: I just removed the referenced of Ms.ajax from from my project